# Cannot turn off line buffering in C

Tags: c, buffer, stdout, stdin

So, I'm working on a big project, and it requires the stdin and stdout buffers to be disabled so that input and output are processed immediately. However, when I try to do that using `setbuf` or `setvbuf`, it just won't work. Here's my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    setbuf(stderr, NULL);
    while(true) {
        char a = getchar();
        printf("%c", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using linux, however I'm not able to test this on a Windows computer so I cannot confirm if this is a linux problem.

Here's a video of it not working: https://youtu.be/EWs5H_6h9DQ

Comment: While you disable buffering for the streams, you still haven't turned of the buffering of the terminal itself. You need to use [termios](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) to set terminal attributes to disable its own line-buffering.

Comment: So many buffers ...

Comment: By the way, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Please try to keep questions self-contained, without the need to use external sites to describe the behavior.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it worked! tysm!!

Comment: since Unix you have a default _cooked_  mode to work with streams, and an optional _raw_ mode.  Under Windows the same things are called LINE INPUT mode. Under Linux use `ioctl` to set the `termios` `struct`, under Windows use the console functions. It is different but similar.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution was to use `termios`. I took the code from [here](https://shtrom.ssji.net/skb/getc.html) and it worked perfectly!

Comment: since Unix you have a default _cooked_  mode to work with streams, and an optional _raw_ mode.  Under Windows the same things are called LINE INPUT mode. Under Linux use `ioctl` to set the `termios` `struct`, under Windows use the console functions. It is different but similar.

Answer (score 0):

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/setvbuf.html

> {_IONBF} shall cause input/output to be unbuffered.

```
setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```